# AspNetCore 'reserved' words

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am having this error when I try to build my application.

Error   RZ1007  "namespace" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.  An explicit expression ("@()") must be used.

This is coming from viewimports

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using OnlineAtrax.Areas.Identity
@namespace OnlineAtrax.Areas.Identity.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Application was OK, until I have updated VS2017 to version 15.7 preview 3.

Comment: Where does the "RZ1007" error come from? That's not Razor. Do you have custom analyzers? Also, why are you trying to set a namespace on a view, or more specifically, on a viewimports file?

Comment: This ViewImport is generated when I have added Identity as scaffold item. And it was working this way. With SDK 2.1 preview-2 final. Now I have SDK 2.1.0 installed from updating VS2017.

Error is comming from ViewImports.

No custom analyzers.

Comment: You can try what it says and wrap it in () @(namespace OnlineAtrax.Areas.Identity.Pages)

Comment: Why Preview 3? 15.7 was released just before the build 2018 a month ago and is now at 15.7.3

Comment: Where do you see preview 7? I mentioned preview 3. Anyway. I did tried to put in brackets, it doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed it. Still VS 15. is out of previews and RCs for quite some time

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem migrating to netcoreapp3.0 and I needed the following in my .csproj file:

`<AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>`